# Having trouble getting WCF-based traffic to show up in JMeter recorder

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm running into an issue with getting the traffic from a WCF-based Windows desktop client to show up in the JMeter recorder - and I'm hoping someone out there might be able to point me in the right direction.

Complicating things a bit, I'm not working directly with the developers of the system, but rather for one of their customers - which somewhat limits my access to some of the information and expertise I would otherwise expect to have.  The client runs over WCF with a binding to an HTTPS endpoint on Azure.

I have JMeter running on the same box as the client.  I have the JMeter Proxy Server working and the ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt in place and working.  The client doesn't have it's own proxy settings, but does appear to be honoring useDefaultWebProxy="true" (as indicated by the client failing with SSL security warnings when the temp cert isn't in place).  However, when I exercise the client with the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder running, none of the traffic to and from the client ever shows up in the recorder.  When I use a browser under the same setup, the traffic is getting recorded as expected.

Being able to get the recorder working is vital because I don't have access to enough information about the client's protocols to try building out tests for them manually (and I suspect it may prove outside of my skillset, given my very limited experience with WCF).

Any useful solutions, suggestions, tips, or pointers would be GREATLY appreciated!

(I'm posting this question in XXXXX to maximize my chances of getting the right answer quickly.  If this type of cross-posting is frowned upon, I apologize for any inconvenience.)

Best,

Justin

"If you can't tell me what you tested, you might as well have not tested."

Answer (score 0):

1. You might need to [set system-wide proxy like](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731131(v=ws.10)#BKMK_2):

   [image]
2. You might need to install [loopback adapter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708322(v=ws.10).aspx) as certain applications cannot route traffic to the local proxy server:

   [image]
3. If nothing helps you can always go for a low-level sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) which is capable of capturing literally every packet sent over the wire, Wi-Fi or USB.

More information: [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter/)